# Can not access to singleton property in swift

Tags: swift, singleton

I'm trying to create singleton and use it.

But when I try to access to its propery, it shows me error.

How can I fix it?

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: You can't call functions like `print` in a class declaration. Such statements need be either be in a function/computed-property/closure/subscript/etc. or at the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
class Test {

    let sharedManager: Manager = {
        var shared = Manager.shared
        shared.str = "update"
        return shared
    }()

}
```

You cannot just put statements like `print` or assignments wherever you want.  Generally, they will be inside functions/closures.  In my example, I am using a closure to get the Manager and initialize it -- the `()` at the end of it calls the closure to cause it to run.